# Button that changes the field

Tags: mysql, forms, ms-access, button

I have a form in Microsoft access.
There should be the button called `Renew`.
When I clicked the button, the one field of the subform should be chanced to todays date.
I created the form and button - > in `From operations` chose `Apply filter`, and -> `Property Sheet` -> `Event` -> `Microsoft Visual Basic`:

```
Private Sub cmd_renew_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_Borrowing SET DateBorrowed = Date()"
DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)
End Sub
```

It does not work and I have no idea is my logic correct or not.
It does not recognise `DateBorrowed`.
I did it in my form, not subform.

Comment: I think using `currentdb.execute stSQL` is more appropriate here, instead of using `docmd.runSQL strSQL`. I am not sure how this relates to your subform though. do you need a where clause?

Comment: you need to requery the subform to reflect the change assuming it is getting run, although your `doesn't work` is a little vague. Error message? Lack of desired outcome?

Comment: @LiamH, May be I need where clause, because I want to update information just for one record. Like if I am in page 3, I want to click the button, and field should update field only in the third page

Comment: It says: cannot find the input table. But I put the name of the table I suppose

Comment: Yes, the SQL you posted above will update EVERY record in that table with the current date, so add the 'where' clause as suggested earlier. We have no idea what 'input table' you mean, or where you get the message, or when. Test your sql in the query designer first, then when satisfied it works, place in the vba code. Please keep updating your original code posting with the latest code you are using.

Comment: SQL is for modifying table fields, In a form you should modify a bound control's value. `me!SubFormControlName.Form!ControlName`. Read [here about referring controls in sub-forms](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
Private Sub cmd_renew_Click()
     Me!SubFormControlName.Form!DateBorrowed = Date()
end Sub
```

Replace SubFormControlName with the actual name of the **Sub-Form Control** in your form.
If you put the Textbox on the main form, remove subform section vrom code:

```
Me!DateBorrowed = Date()
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me then please, I did it in just main form, not subform. How do I need to change my statement?